# Why does my code does not have decimal? c#

Tags: c#, decimal

Why does my result does not have decimal?

```
***///Get api/example/{id}
///Get api/example/33 -> 4
public string GET (int id)
   { int product = id/7;
     return product;
   }***
```

If the input number is 33, I would get the answer '4' without decimal, it does not even round up.

Comment: Hint: `product` is an integer type. If you want a fraction use a float or decimal type. If you want to round, use `Math.Round()`.

Comment: Hi Sunny. Please [edit] the question and clarify if the problem is the lack of decimal, or the truncation method (lack of rounding). The post and the title are a bit confusing since those are two different questions.

Comment: Please post real code. `product` is an `int` so C# has a compiler error when you try to return it for a function with a `string` return type.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are storing result of you calculation in a variable of data type "int". int can not take fractional values. Use float or double to get decimal points.

Also in C# when you do division and if both the numerator and the denominator are integers then result will be integer. So to convert it to decimal point you will need to convert either denominator or both to decimal.

You can to like this..

```
    float product = (float)id/(float)7; or
    float product = id/7f; // using literals
```

So your function should look like this..

```
public string GET (int id)
{ 
    float product = id/7f;
    return product.ToString();
}
```

Also use ToString() on final product result while returning because your method expect String value as return type.

hint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: `id/7` doesn't _return_ a fractional value. Also, this code doesn't compile.

Comment: Could you please share error message here ?

Comment: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'string'

Comment: But even if we change `return product;` to `return product.ToString();` to fix that error, calling `GET(33)` returns `"4"`: [Example](https://rextester.com/YDTP47542).

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I posted answer in hurry. I have edit the main answer, please check. Also I have provided the description of solution.